# How to render json data from a function?

Tags: django

I am using a tutorial on Django sessions, where there is a function written to delete session on logout url call, but i want to use Ajax to call that function but problem is ajax giving error as im returning HttpResponse instead of any json response so can i know how to convert this function to render some json response?

views.py

```
def logout(request):
   try:
      del request.session['username']
   except:
      pass
   return HttpResponse("<strong>You are logged out.</strong>")
```

url.py

```
url(r'^logout/', 'logout', name = 'logout')
```

Comment: Why do you want JSON here at all? And why are you storing your username in the session? And why do you have a blank `except`? If the tutorial is slowing you any of this code, you need to find a better one straight away.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ajax shows error that `return HttpResponse("<strong>You are logged out.</strong>")` as i'm using ajax to call this function.

2- I'm saving user name so when a user leave site without logout when he comes back i can render his logged in page as username is unique.

3- sir im just following a tutorial..

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is there anyything wrong with this code?

Comment: Look at using a [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) instead of a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: @dirkgroten JsonResponse what? i mean here im just deleting a session what should i return as json?

Comment: Your javascript would always want to have some kind of a response. If everything is ok, you send back something like `{'status': 'ok'}` and your script checks if `data.status` is actually `"ok"`. In case of error, i.e. instead of `pass` you would respond with `{'status': 'not ok', 'error': 'the text of your error'}` so the script would be able to display the error to the user.

Comment: But I agree with @DanielRoseman that this tutorial is teaching you very bad habits: 1) you should not logout users by deleting the session, use the built-in `logout(request)` instead 2) you should not logout on a GET but only on a POST request and 3) you should handle exceptions properly as this one affects the user.